# Can I make the Finder label a folder if it contains a file or folder of a specific name?

Tags: finder, automator, script

I'd love it if I could somehow make the Finder color-label all folders containing a .git directory so I could tell at a glance if the folder is a Git repo. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Folder Actions http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/

Comment: @mankoff thanks for the suggestion, but aren't folder actions tied to specific folders? Or can I make a folder action that is attached to ALL folders, even newly created ones?

Comment: Oh you are probably right. OK. Perhaps you'll need to code. See SCPlugin, the SVN Finder Plugin. It changes folder and file icons based on SVN status.

Comment: Or, cron job with a 'find' or 'mdfind' command, calling AppleScript? There are an infinite number of hack-ish ways to do this. Not sure about the best formal method.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this question and realized the answer would be useful to me too. Here's the Applescript I came up with. Copy it into Applescript Editor, and adjust the two variables `theSearchPath` (first line) and the index number at the end of the `set label index` line and you should be good to go.

I'm searching `~/projects` and coloring the results green in this case.

```
set theSearchPath to "/Users/Me/projects"
set theResults to do shell script "find " & quoted form of theSearchPath & " -name .git"

repeat with i from 1 to (count paragraphs of theResults)
  set theResult to paragraph i of theResults
  set theParentPath to text 1 through ((length of theResult) - 5) of theResult
  set theParentAlias to POSIX file (theParentPath) as alias
  tell application "Finder"
    set label index of theParentAlias to 6
    -- Set the last value of the above line to correspond with the color you want.
    -- 0 is no color
    -- 1 is orange
    -- 2 is red
    -- 3 is yellow
    -- 4 is blue
    -- 5 is purple
    -- 6 is green
    -- 7 is gray
  end tell
end repeat
```

Note: It hasn't been written to gracefully handle errors spit out by the `find` command. As long as you're searching directories you have permissions on, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Vickash's script didn't work for me so I updated it, and revised it slightly to be able to find any file extension by specifying the extension in the variable `theFileExtension` (in my case, .flac files.) Works in Sierra.

```
set theSearchPath to "/Users/Me/projects"
set theFileExtension to ".flac"
set theResults to do shell script "find " & quoted form of theSearchPath & " -name *"&theFileExtension

repeat with i from 1 to (count paragraphs of theResults)
    set theResult to paragraph i of theResults
    set thePath to text 1 through ((length of theResult)) of theResult
    tell application "Finder"
        set theParentAlias to container of (POSIX file (thePath) as alias)
        set label index of theParentAlias to 1
        -- Set the last value of the above line to correspond with the color you want.
        -- 0 is no color
        -- 1 is orange
        -- 2 is red
        -- 3 is yellow
        -- 4 is blue
        -- 5 is purple
        -- 6 is green
        -- 7 is gray
    end tell
end repeat
```